# networkx draws independent figures on top of each other

Tags: python, networkx

I want to draw some different topology figures in a study. However, I see that after I draw the first figure, I see it inherited in the second figure. I am using anaconda2 and its networkx package. Here is a sample code for different cases.

```
#!/path/to/anaconda2/bin/python
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

val=int(sys.argv[1])

def drawV1(numOfNodes,FilePtr):
    np.random.seed(0)
    G = nx.Graph()
    for ii in range(1,numOfNodes+1):
        G.add_node(str(ii))
    nx.draw(G, with_labels = True)
    plt.savefig(FilePtr) # save as png

def drawV2(numOfNodes,FilePtr):
    np.random.seed(0)
    G2 = nx.Graph()
    for ii in range(1,numOfNodes+1):
        G2.add_node(str(ii))
    nx.draw(G2, with_labels = True)
    plt.savefig(FilePtr) # save as png


if val==1: # Problematic case
    drawV1(5,'V1_1_1.png')
    drawV1(10,'V1_1_2.png')
if val==2: # it is good when I draw only one figure
    drawV1(10,'V1_2_1.png')
if val==3: # problem again
    drawV1(10,'V1_3_1.png')
    drawV2(10,'V2_3_2.png')
```

I run it as

```
./mycode.py [1,2,3]
```

For example for case 1, I get the following plots:

[5 nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89aum.png)

[10 nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5gFP.png) (you will see previous 5 nodes too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `nx.draw` with `hold=False` or add `plt.clf()` after `plt.savefig(...)`. It clears the figure and you can draw the new one.